# how to get secrets from broken docker swarm

Tags: docker, docker-swarm

My swarm server is broken(Linux system error), sadly it is only one node.

I read https://docs.docker.com/v17.09/engine/swarm/admin_guide/#back-up-the-swarm

**So I tried to backup `/var/lib/docker/swarm` and restore it on a new set up docker server as below:**

The new docker daemon works fine without any swarm feature, but swarm feature doesn't work like:

```
$ docker service ls
Error response from daemon: This node is not a swarm manager. Use "docker swarm init" or "docker swarm join" to connect this node to swarm and try again.
```

I think that I need to force re-init swarm manager:

```
docker swarm init --force-new-cluster
```

After that, every command relate to swarm like

```
docker service ls
```

has no response, **those make docker daemon hang**.

Then I tried to extract data from back files, and I found this https://medium.com/lucjuggery/raft-logs-on-swarm-mode-1351eff1e690 seems useful. But I still can't recovery secrets.

Only get something like:

```
 secrets: <
        secret_id: "6vtndjswxr4fe9kxjtmmtk6af"
        secret_name: "DATABASE_ADMIN_URL"
        file: <
          name: "_DATABASE_ADMIN_URL"
          uid: "0"
          gid: "0"
          mode: -r--r--r--
        >
      >
```

which doesn't include useful data.

BTW: I'm not hacking the server, I hope recovery the data instead of going investigate all configs for bundle service.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It took me few hours today to figure out why docker daemon hangs after

```
docker swarm init --force-new-cluster
```

I believe there is one step missing from the official doc https://docs.docker.com/v17.09/engine/swarm/admin_guide/#restore-from-a-backup

**Because after I removed `docker-state.json` then ran**

```
docker swarm init --force-new-cluster --advertise-addr <the-server-ip>:2377
```

things work as expect.